# keep getting unresolved external symbol with a void

Tags: c++, imgui

In this project of mine which is for IMGUI using minhook i keep getting an unresolved external symbol for `void _cdecl Hooking::KillHook(void)` within initalize.cpp

and idk if im dumb or something but i can't find it out. so iv finnally decided to ask online for this stuff.

heres code from hook.h

```
void KillHook() noexcept;
```

hook.cpp

```
void Hooking::KillHook() noexcept
{
    MH_DisableHook(MH_ALL_HOOKS);
    MH_RemoveHook(MH_ALL_HOOKS);
    MH_Uninitialize();
}
```

and here is where i use it in initalize.cpp *note* this is within a void startup() and it starts with a `try` and `catch` in catch it goes to QUITMENU

```
// are we dead?
QUITMENU:

    // kill both
    Hooking::KillHook();
    Menu::KillMenu();

    // this allows threading to no die
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(Inizst, 0);
```

i hope someone knows why this is happening it's been backing me from finishing this for 2 days now

Comment: Are you actually compiling `hook.cpp`?

Comment: yes i am everything in my sln project is included

Comment: Please show a [mre] including the full error message